# Faild to import gdal/ogr modules in python2 environment for Anuga model

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdal

I installed anuga from https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/anuga_core.
Aunga work on python2 instead of python3.
After installation of anuga, i run the runtests.py in terminal window to testify that all required environment is created.

> Python version 2.7.18 and gdal 3.0.4  were already installed

**After running the test file, i am getting the following error:**

ImportError: Failed to import gdal/ogr modules --perhaps gdal python interface is not installed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/file_conversion/tests/test_csv2sts.py", line 92, in test_run_via_commandline
self._check_generated_sts()
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/file_conversion/tests/test_csv2sts.py", line 97, in _check_generated_sts
sts = NetCDFFile(sts_out,'r')
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/file/netcdf.py", line 62, in NetCDFFile
return Dataset(file_name, netcdf_mode, format='NETCDF3_64BIT')
File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2123, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.**init**
File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1743, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sts_out.sts'

### ======================================================================
ERROR: test_Make_Geotif (test_plot_utils.Test_plot_utils)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/utilities/tests/test_plot_utils.py", line 407, in test_Make_Geotif
EPSG_CODE=32756, output_dir='.', CellSize=myCellSize)
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/utilities/plot_utils.py", line 1004, in Make_Geotif
raise ImportError, msg
ImportError: Failed to import gdal/ogr modules --perhaps gdal python interface is not installed.

### ======================================================================
ERROR: test_Make_Geotif_with_knn (test_plot_utils.Test_plot_utils)

### Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/utilities/tests/test_plot_utils.py", line 440, in test_Make_Geotif_with_knn
k_nearest_neighbours=4)
File "/home/satyukt/Projects/anuga/anuga_core/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anuga/utilities/plot_utils.py", line 1004, in Make_Geotif
raise ImportError, msg
ImportError: Failed to import gdal/ogr modules --perhaps gdal python interface is not installed.

Ran 1252 tests in 94.942s

FAILED (errors=14)

> **How can i import gdal/ogr modules in python2 environment?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your GDAL version. The default one is 2.2 but now it is not supported by ANUGA python-2. Previously GDAL 3.0.4 was supporting ANUGA python-2 but the GDAL-3.0.4 now supporting only python3.x.
Hence the supporting version now is: GDAL-2.4.2

You can install it in your conda env by using the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal=2.4.2
```